# Getting java.lang.AbstractMethodError at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.register while running liquibase

Tags: liquibase

Hi i have recently updated from liquibase 2.0.3 to 3.3.3.
so while running the liquibase against any database i am getting the following error.

```
SEVERE 7/10/15 9:47 AM: liquibase: Unknown Reason
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.register(DatabaseFactory.java:87)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.<init>(DatabaseFactory.java:29)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.getInstance(DatabaseFactory.java:40)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:50)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:884)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:175)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:94
```

)

I am running from command prompt like this :

> liquibase --logLevel=severe --logFile=tesaaa1
>   --classpath=D:\JenzabarFull\ngp-configurations\trunk\jx-financialaid\jx-financialaid-ear\target\jx-financialaid-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear
>   update

The liquibase properties file is :

> changeLogFile=changelog.xml driver: org.postgresql.Driver url:
>   jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/NGP_DB username: jdbcusr password:
>   password defaultSchemaName: ngp

Comment: Do you have the old liquibase 2.x jar in your classpath somewhere?

Comment: No, its having the latest liquibase core jar.

Comment: When I had a similar issue I discovered the culprit (2 different versions of liquibase on the classpath) by step debugging through the "register" method  mentioned in Jens' answer.

Comment: Is this a grails app?  In which case you have liquibase-core-2.0.5.jar in the Grails User Library.  I have no clue how to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Just by looking at the liquibase code and trying to determine what could go wrong I think liquibase might not have identified the correct database.

You could try to add the database class as a parameter to your liquibase commandline, like this: `--databaseClass=liquibase.database.core.PostgresDatabase`.

Comment: Tried giving in Both the places ( liquibase properties and as a command line option) , but still facing the same error. I am running against mt EAR file, it works find for my other EAR application but one of the application does not work with the same, any idea you can suggest probably the reason of error.

This implementation has been changed in 3.3.*

Comment: public void register(Database database) {
        Map<String, SortedSet<Database>> map = null;
        if (database instanceof InternalDatabase) {
            map = internalDatabases;
        } else {
            map = implementedDatabases;

        }

        if (!map.containsKey(database.getShortName())) {
            map.put(database.getShortName(), new TreeSet<Database>(new TreeSet<Database>(new DatabaseComparator())));
        }
        map.get(database.getShortName()).add(database);
    }

Comment: I'm sorry I can't reproduce your problem. So it is kind a hard to tell.

Comment: 3.4.1 will have some additional logging for this issue to hopefully help troubleshooting.